# Colocar um texto dentro da imagem

Tags: css, html5

Aqui esta o meu codigo

```css
 .imgs{
   position:absolute;
   margin-top: -180px; 
   margin-left: 25px; 
   width: 200px; 
   height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<td style="width: 200px;"><?php echo '<img width=200px; src="'.$imagens[$aleatorio].'"'; ?></td>
  <figcaption style="width: 200px;" class="imgs"><?php  echo $list; ?></figcaption>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o `position: absolute;` e mudar o local do texto com `left` , `top`, `right` e `bottom`

Para textos largos demais você pode usar o `max-width` e definir o tamanho máximo

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  top: 75px;
  color: white;
  max-width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSG2SKL5FJaXqyHfvxrxb5NmQ4ZcWgCPyaZvqEB0qsSubAyQHOBkw">
  <span>texto muito largo para caber em uma linha</span>
</div>
```

Comment: resolve resolve, porem vou ter quer fazer isso pra todas as telas, 
Porem quando eu escrevo ele ultrapassa a imagem, 
mas a sugestão é valida

Comment: Editei a pergunta com uma solução simples para isso

Comment: ok, obrigadão valeu.